# Set value option is inactive in webstorm debug

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

I have a problem in WebStorm’s debug Tool with the variables panel. When i am debugging a node.js application the “Set value” option is inactive.
What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please vote: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13411